# While using .groupby function InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, error-handling

I want to group data sets in a dataframe df. All data fields are to be grouped and the maximum value is to be taken from column "A". I use the following code for this:

`df = df.groupby(by=["A"]).max()`

But I get the following message:

`InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

What does this error mean and what is the cause?

Comment: you should include a sample of your data that produces the error.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do that because of data protection. Since I don't know what the cause of the problem is, I can't illustrate the case with dummy data.

Comment: You should be able to mask your data with all `x` for string and `0` for numbers and see if the problem persists (I bet it would). Change the column name to further protect your sensitive data, see if the problem still persists. At this point if it still does, you can surely post that data here.

Comment: before using group by can you try: df.reset_index(drop = True,inplace = True)

Comment: @Ugur Yigit unfortunately, this did not solve the problem

Comment: can you tell me what does  df.index.is_unique return ? If it is false then it means you dont have unique index and thats why you got the error.

Comment: Using ``df.index.is_unique`` my output is ``True``

Answer (score 0):

Did I understand correctly that you want to get the maximum value of column A? If so, you don't need grouping. Your solution is as follows:

```
maxvalue = df['A'].max()
```

If you want get df with max A values, you should use it:

```
df = df[df['A'] == df['A'].max()]
```

groupby is calculate max of other columns if A is category, for example, max costs of car models - it is aggregation method